# Changing HttpMessageHandler in HttpClient

Tags: c#, http

[HttpClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient.ASPx) takes an [HttpMessageHandler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpmessagehandler.aspx) argument in two of its constructors.

Is there any easy way to change the handler after the HttpClient has been created without creating a new HttpClient instance?

Comment: Use decoraiter pattern or facade to create wrapper handler which derives from httpmessagehandler. Add a method to this implementation to set inner handler. Now pass your handler to http client using a variable and use that to change inner handler.

Answer (score 2):

If you keep a reference to the actual `Handler`, then you can modify the Handler after it has been created and inserted into the `HttpClient`. Not sure if you can change it to another Handler type however.

It's pretty dumb that you cannot retrieve the Handler through the `HttpClient` reference, such as `HttpClient.Handler`, but what I mentioned above works.

Comment: Does not work really. It seems they do a copy and not pass by ref. Only way to do it is to reinstantiate the HttpClient.

Answer (score -1):

best way, afaik, is to check the source of the default HttpClientFactory which actually does pooling of handlers etc. - and then create your own implementation of IHttpClientFactory - for example just alter the default one in a way, that you can actually send the HttpClient to a method in order to get the reference to it's handler as return value. This is ofc just a quick thought, due to pooling and expiration mechanisms of the default implementation it might be suboptimal - but the default implementation gives a great insight into the mechanics.

It made me for example create my own handler type, which allows changing assigned IWebProxy, doing selective DNS requests, assigning DNS & IP overrides etc. And btw relying on the principles of IHttpClientFactory results in a nice seperation of concerns.

You could for example do pooling with different pre-defined ClientHandler types  & properties, and just add an IOption to the GetClient call, which contains like a RequestedHandlerType, IHttpClientMessageHandlerOptions etc. , and keep letting the the whole DI mechanisms behind the scene do its solid work. And by actually requesting Handlers with options , defined in the DI container, you will have a so much cleaner code base, than with on-the-fly alteration.